# Handling Non-Serializable Object Attribute Checks in Parallel Processing with Python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, stable-baselines

I'm facing a somewhat peculiar issue with Python and hoping for insights or solutions. Let's say I have a class containing a non-serializable object attribute (and changing this is not an option as the code is not mine), structured as follows:

```
class Class1:
    def __init__(self, non_serial_obj):
        self.non_serial_obj = non_serial_obj

class Class2:
    def __init__(self, obj_class1):
        self.obj_class1 = obj_class1

    def foo(self):
        return True
```

Additionally, `Class2` includes a method named `foo`, which in this case simply returns `True`. So far, so good.

However, the problem arises when parallelizing the processing of multiple `Class2` instances and checking for the existence of the `foo` attribute. An error occurs indicating that the object is not serializable due to the inability to communicate its code, although invoking the method itself does not cause any issues.

Is there a way to enable attribute checks to also work with this structure in a parallel processing context? To potentially aid in finding a solution, I'm using `get_attr` and `env_method` methods from the [SubprocVecEnv](https://stable-baselines3.readthedocs.io/en/master/_modules/stable_baselines3/common/vec_env/subproc_vec_env.html#SubprocVecEnv) class for invoking object methods in each process.

Any guidance or workaround would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "non-serializable object" means that it cannot be serialized *automatically*. If you want to transfer this object between processes, you will need to serialize it manually. If you don't need to transfer the object, and instead just want to know about the `foo` attribute, then only transfer the `foo` attribute rather than the entire object.